# how to display highest order count i,e is in table(tcount) with customer name( name)

Tags: mysql

I created 2 tables: customers (table1) and orderss (table2)

In table1 I created `columns(id,name)` and in table2 I created `columns(oid,customer_id,amount)`.

Next I used the `sum()` function to get the total amount of particular customers and I used `count()` to get the count of total orders ordered by particular customer and I displayed respectively using `group by`.

Now I do not know how to find the highest orders with particular customer name.

This is what I tried:

```
select max(name) as aaa,max(tcount) as highorders
from
   ( SELECT name,sum(orderss.amount) AS tamount,count(orderss.oid) as tcount
     FROM customers
     INNER JOIN orderss ON customers.id=orderss.customer_id group by name
     having tamount > 50 and tcount >= 2
   ) as ho
```

Comment: see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

use `order by`

```
select max(name) as aaa,max(tcount) as highorders
from
   ( SELECT name,sum(orderss.amount) AS tamount,count(orderss.oid) as tcount
     FROM customers
     INNER JOIN orderss ON customers.id=orderss.customer_id group by name
     having tamount > 50 and tcount >= 2
   ) as ho
order by field_name DESC
```

(you can get an ascending order by replacing DESC with ASC